# "certificate verify failed" when connecting docker-compose to IBM Container Cloud

Tags: docker, cloud, paas, docker-compose

I have a local Ubuntu 14.04 with the cloudfoundry CLI, docker and the IBM Containers Plugin installed into the cloudfoundry CLI.

I've pushed all local docker images to the IBM repository.

I run

> cf login -a https://api.ng.bluemix.net
> cf ic login

Then I switch to the remote docker cloud by exporting os env variables as the output of "cf ic login" by issuing the following commands

> export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net:8443
>
> export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/root/.ice/certs
>
> export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1

I run

> docker ps

and I see the instances running in the IBM Cloud - so I'm convinced these settings are correct.

Now I run

> docker-compose up

in a docker-compose project, but now I get

> SL error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)

I've also set

> export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=0

but this doesn't help either..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker Compose is not yet supported within IBM Containers, but the development team is actively working on adding Compose to the production environment.

Comment: Does anybody know if this is still the case as of Feb 2016?  I get the same error and hoping Bluemix has since picked up support for docker-compose.

Comment: I cheated and asked a friend .. as of Feb 2016 docker-compose is still not supported with IBM Containers.